# How to provide a filter based on json:api for referencing nodes with a term reference field?

Tags: 8

I am working with the [Entity Share](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_share) module to synchronize content between Drupal instances and I need a filter to define which content can be shared.

My use case is almost identical to the one mentioned in [this support issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_share/issues/2986929). The only differences being that the content type is a basic page and the term reference field is called `field_share_to` which in turn references a taxonomy vocab called `Sites`. I also have only two sites; 1 server and 1 client.

I am struggling to configure the correct path for term reference field and value for the term ID(64)

> Enter the machine name of the field / property you want to filter on. You can reference field / property of a referenced entity. Example: uid.name for the name of the author.

So. How to define the machine name for the jsonapi property that would return nodes filtered by term id 64?

I ask this question as a site builder rather than someone who spends a lot of time working with code.

Answer (score 0):

The module maintainer was able to provide with the answer.

field_share_to.entity.tid = 64

And also with a [link to further reading](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/filtering)